# Defining a default route for a subdomain within Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to setup a subdomain within my Rails 2.3.10 application, using SubdomainFu - trying to setup m.domainname.com  The aspect that I'm struggling with is trying to define a default route for the subdomain that is different than the default route for the main application.

If this is my route namespace for my subdomain:

```
map.namespace :mobile, :path_prefix => '', :conditions => { :subdomain => 'm' } do |mobile|
  map.connect '/', :controller => 'mobile/mobile'
end
```

and then a little further down in my routes file, I have my default route:

```
map.default '/', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'home'
```

The default route for the namespace is overriding the main default route.  If I move the primary default route above the namespace, then it takes precedence.

Any suggestions on how to best structure the route file and define a default route for the subdomain?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of rails are you using, it is significant as routing has changed a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The line `map.connect '/'` within the namespace block is still using the main `map` object, which means that the routes are matching as if the namespace block around it have disappeared (and so the first route that matches -- the mobile controller -- is being used.)

Changing it to `mobile.connect '/' ...` (i.e use the `mobile` block variable that you've created) should fix the error you're seeing.